# Can i use BETWEEN checkin and checkout in different datetimes?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * 
  from reserva
     , casa  
 where casa.lotacao = '$tamanho' 
   and reserva.Casa_id = '$product_id' 
   and reserva.checkout = '$checkout' BETWEEN  reserva.checkin ='$checkin'
```

> reserva = reservation
> casa = home

I want to get for an example

```
Check-in 15-06-2016
check-out 20-06-2016
```

I want that 5 days to close.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: `SELECT 9 BETWEEN 4=2;` Seriously, who upvotes this stuff, and why?

Comment: SELECT 9 BETWEEN 4=2; WTF??!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. But your syntax is wrong:

```
SELECT.... $checkout BETWEEN '$checkin' AND DATE_SUB('$checkin',INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: But I want to get checkout and checkin from the users and close the days between checkin and checkout.

Comment: I don't understand what 'close the days' means. There are many date functions in MySQL - DATEDIFF is one: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff